# Output a variable within an else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to pull `$username` from my database as a greeting. How would I output a variable within my else statement?

The variable username is equal to the following:

```
$username =  htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


<?php
if($_GET["p"] == 'login') {
echo "";
} else {
echo "<div class='row'><div class='logo'><img style='margin-left: -21px;' src='http://localhost/ncms/images/logo.png' /></div><p class='panel radius topinfo'>Welcome    . $username .</p>";
}?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? You're concatenating when you don't need to, but you should still be seeing the username.

Comment: Plus, you don't close the `<div class='row'>`. Did you check the resulting HTML? The username _should_ be there, even if you'll see those concatenating dots around it...

Comment: Are you sure there is a value in $username?

Comment: htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); returns my username, but <?PHP echo $username ?> in my page content returns root. But in my head, it returns nothing. I have not a clue what that is about.

Comment: A bit more investigating, echoing $_SESSION['user']['username'] returns what I want. Still isnt outputting in my <p> tag area

Answer (score 0):

You could use string formatting.

```
printf("<div class='row'><div class='logo'><img style='margin-left: -21px;' src='http://localhost/ncms/images/logo.png' /></div><p class='panel radius topinfo'>Welcome %s</p>", $username);
```

Answer (score 0):

when using the double quote you don't need to concatenate the text string. you can change it to

```
echo "<div class='row'><div class='logo'><img style='margin-left: -21px;' src='http://localhost/ncms/images/logo.png' /></div><p class='panel radius topinfo'>Welcome $username</p>";
```

I did not attempt to fix the errors in the code other than the question asked. Validators should be used as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Php variables auto-expand when used in double quotes, but these are usually used for specifying attribute vales in HTML.

I find the easiest way to remember the rules when echoing HTML is to use single quotes for the HTML, double quotes for the attribute values and string concatonation for php variables.

```
echo '<div class="row"><div class="logo"><img style="margin-left: -21px;" src="http://localhost/ncms/images/logo.png" /></div></div><p class="panel radius topinfo">Welcome '. $username .'</p>';
```

You're also missing a closing div (added above).

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Fixed it. Sorry for the confusion to you guys on this one, I had to put the variable inside of my function set that starts the session. Doh!

Sorry again guys and thank you for the tips though I forgot how to concatenate for a second there lol.